# Accessing a function, that has been called

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, anonymous-function

I am currently trying to figure out a way to writer a "telephone book". (It's a task from university so I would appreciate a tip rather than a full solution)

I created a function which enables the user to write in several names as follows:

(It had to be solves like this, because we had to use `type TelephoneBook = String -> String`)

```
(enterName "Peter" "4232" (enterName "Alice" "23213" emptyBook)) ""
```

This would then return `Peter`.

Well now I am supposed to be able to access this data and search for a name and then retrieve a Number.
My current Idea is as follows:

```
searchFkt :: String -> TelephoneBook -> String
searchFkt a b 
 | (a == book "") = a         --Iam fully aware that this doesn't work
 | otherwise = "not found"
```

I am aware that the second part doesn't work like that (`searchFkt :: String -> TelephoneBook -> String` was given as well), however I have no clue how to implement this and I really need help, because I have been looking through books and trying to wrap myself around how to solve this for hours.

Thanks in advance

Ps: I want to understand how this works and not just have a solution, so maybe a reference to what to read would be helpful as well :)

Comment: Why would it return `Peter`?

Comment: What is the type and purpose of `enterName`? It would appear to be `enterName :: String -> String -> TelephoneBook -> TelephoneBook`, but then why would you expect applying the new `TelephoneBook` value to an empty string to return `"Peter"`?

Comment: In the example we had given of a console in which they typed the above shown it returned the name, so I implemented it as follows: 'putName :: String -> String -> Telephonebook -> TelephoneBook' (this was given) 'putName a b c = (\x -> b)' <- my code

Comment: And what is `putName` supposed to do? Why does it take 3 arguments if it ignores two of them?

Comment: @Fapprentice: but then you completely forget about the original telephone book and furthermore all elements will map on Peter here...

Comment: @chepner: I think he wants to say `enterName` and add a name to the book.

Comment: what was given were the following: `enterName :: String -> String -> Telebook -> Telebook` and the type `type Telebook = String -> String` as well as `search:: String -> Telebook -> String` I kinda when of what...

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem could you further elaborate why everything would map on peter in this case - that sounds like being a huge issue I haven't noticed yet

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I realize that. It's not clear that the OP does, though.

Comment: I will be meeting with other students and trying to figure out the problem, I hope I explained it clearly enough to understand if not I am very sorry. Still thank you for taking the time to help :)

Comment: One thing I may have missed or forgotten (but appears to be addressed by Willem Van Onsem in his answer): were you *give* the type `type TelephoneBook = String -> String`, or is that how you decided to implement the type?

Comment: I was given this type, in all functions we were given how to implement them (the `myfuction :: String -> Telbook` etc was always given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you say `Telephonebook` is a type alias `String -> String`, I think you want to compose a function that maps names onto telephone number. So that if you lookup `"Peter"` from the book, it returns `"4232"`.

Now if you want to search for a name, all you have to do is *call* the query on the telephonebook. So `searchFkt` would look like:

```
searchFkt :: String -> Telephonebook -> String
searchFkt query book = book query
```

Nevertheless based on your comments, I think you made an error in your `enterName` program. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781995/accessing-a-function-that-has-been-called#comment70754285_41781995) you say you implemented it as:

```
putName :: String -> String -> Telephonebook -> Telephonebook
putName name number oldbook = \x -> number
```

(I took the liberty to rename `a`, `b` and `c`.). As you can see, `name` and `oldbook` are not even mentioned in the right side of the expression. As a result Haskell forgets about these: it thus means that nor `name`, nor `oldbook` play any part in the construction of the new book.

A better way would be to implement it as:

```
putName :: String -> String -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
putName name number oldbook = newbook
    where newbook query | query == name = number
                        | otherwise = oldbook query
```

In other words you construct a new function `newbook` that takes as input a `query` (the name you are supposed to resolve). In case `query` is equal to the given new `name`, it returns the `number`; otherwise it asks the `oldbook` to handle it further.

Finally I think it is not a good idea to implement the phonebook as a function `String -> String`, because a next task might be to implement a reverse lookup operation, in which case you are lost. It is better to implement it as a list of tuples like `[(String,String)]` (of course hashmaps, etc. would be more ideal).

Comment: Wow, this was fast :) thank you very much, I don't know HashMaps and querys yet so I'll habe to have a look into that! But your explanation makes sense

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, per se, but an attempt to clarify what your assignment appears to be, both for your sake and the sake of others trying to read your question(s).

---

The ultimate goal of your assignment appears to be to implement a phone book using a function; a hard-coded example might be

```
type TelephoneBook = String -> String

myPhoneBook :: TelephoneBook
myPhoneBook "Peter" = "4232"
myPhoneBook "Alice" = "23213"
```

Note that this is only a partial function; it is not defined at all for the vast majority of possible names.

One problem with this approach is that it doesn't allow for a truly empty phone book, since you can't define a function that doesn't actually do *anything*. So, we'll replace that with an "empty" book that returns a default value for any name not already in the phone book:

```
-- Not ideal, but it's the best we can do given the constraints
-- imposed by the given type.
empty :: TelephoneBook
empty _ = "not found"
```

Your goal is to write a function `enterName` that takes a name, a phone number, and an *existing* phone book, and returns a new phone book that is the same as the old one, but with one new entry (that overrides any previous entry with the same name. That is,

```
empty "Peter" == "not found"
(enterName "Peter" "1234" empty) "Peter" == "1234"
(enterName "Peter" "1234" empty) "Bob" == "not found"
(enterName "Bob" "9876" (enterName "Peter" "1234" empty)) "Bob" == "9876"
```

Your `enterName` function has type `String -> String -> TelephoneBook -> TelephoneBook`, meaning it takes three arguments, and it needs to actually do something with all three of them.

```
enterName :: String -> String -> TelephoneBook -> TelephoneBook
enterName name number phonebook = ...
```

Likewise, your `searchFkt :: String -> TelephoneBook -> String` function takes a name and a phone book and returns the number associated with that name in the book.

```
searchFkt :: String -> TelephoneBook -> String
searchFkt name book = ...
```

Given the definition of `TelephoneBook` above and the examples of its use, it should be obvious how to implement `searchFkt`.